# Spring RestTemplate - How to not interpret parameter placeholders

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a Spring Boot Java application that needs to make a REST GET call to a service to retrieve some information. I keep running into problems and I suspect it is because the call has embedded curly braces (`{` and `}`). For example, here is the REST call:

```
GET https://<URL>/api/v1/query?query=count by(__name__) ({__name__=~'.+'})
```

Note: The query value is Prometheus query language (PromQL). It is valid and works fine (as long as it's URL encoded) in Postman.

At first I was URL encoding the query parameter value in my app as well and that was causing other strange errors. We wondered whether there was double encoding going on, so I turned off the encoding part and passed it as-is. Now I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] 2023-05-22 13:14:12.663 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:175) - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '__name__=~'.+''] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand '__name__=~'.+''
```

If I understand correctly, the curly braces signify a query parameter that's provided when the GET call is made. However, in this case, the curly braces are **not** intended as a parameter placeholder for the REST call, but rather needs to be passed on as-is so that Prometheus can process the query.

The code making the call does not attempt to pass any parameters.

Is there a way to have `RestTemplate` not try to interpret the curly braces as parameter placeholders?

Comment: Pass your own UriTemplateHandler to setUriTemplateHandler() ?

Comment: Any of examples of how that can be done? Not finding much.

Comment: Have you tried the UriComponentBuilder for building the URL? maybe something like this:
`UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://<URL>/api/v1/query").queryParam("query", "count by(__name__) ({__name__=~'.+'})");` then you can pass the URL to your `exchange` or `getForObject` calls like this `builder.build().encode().toUri()`